# Using text/markdown in emails

Tags: email, markdown

Do I have to expect any problems on the recipientsʼ side if I started sending single-part emails as `Content-Type: text/markdown; charset=UTF-8;` according to RFCs [7763](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7763) and [7764](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7764)? I believe it should fall back safely to the default `text/plain`.

---

There are several ways email clients can support Markdown/Commonmark or related [languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language). I'm talking about *transmission* and the resulting *display* here.

### Input

- Convert asterisks, underscores etc. the user inputs with their keyboard to HTML tags (or, in theory, any other rich text format) and send the email as a multipart message with `text/plain` and `text/html`.
- Like above, but also offer GUI buttons or keyboard shortcuts (e.g. `foo` + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> ⇒ `_foo_`) to aid the input of these formats. This is basically a rich text editor that generates a better plain-text fallback than most do currently.

Both of these can use no, inline, side-by-side or before-submission previews of the rendered text.

This is what plugins like [Markdown Here](https://markdown-here.com/) can do and some (web)mail clients support natively, e.g. [Airmail](http://docs.airmailapp.com/airmail-for-mac/composer/markdown-composer-airmail-for-macos), [Mail Mate](https://manual.mailmate-app.com/preferences.html#markup_support), [Mailspring](https://github.com/Foundry376/Mailspring/issues/19#issuecomment-359641208), [Gmelius](https://gmelius.com/markdown-gmail/), [Cypht](https://cypht.org/features.html). Some newsletter, admin, [ticket](https://docs.pretix.eu/en/latest/user/markdown.html) or shop systems that send out emails themselves can also handle markdown input in this way.

### Transmission

- Send single-part messages as `text/markdown` instead of the standard `text/plain`, relying on graceful fallback to the latter. *This is what I'm asking about!*
- Send multi-part messages with `text/markdown` instead of `text/html`, basically duplicating the `text/plain` message body.
- Send multi-part messages with generated `text/html` and `text/markdown` instead of the usual `text/plain` basic version.

[Mail Mate](https://manual.mailmate-app.com/preferences.html#markup_support) and [Groups.io](https://beta.groups.io/g/main/message/1318) may add a header parameter like this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; format=flowed; markup=markdown
```

### Display

- Display received single-part mails that have the appropriate `text/markdown` header set as plain text, as if it were `text/plain`. *This is the expected graceful fallback.*
- Display received single-part or multi-part mails that have the `Content-Type` header set with a `text/markdown` type or `markup=markdown` parameter as rich text with the formatting characters removed.
- Display received single-part mails that pass some heuristics to determine they were written according to Markdown or some other [LML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language) conventions as rich text with the formatting characters possibly being kept.

Many clients, e.g. Apple Mail, support rich text rendering of a single Markdown feature: block quotations with (possibly nested) `>` at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 3):

[Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)
has been implemented in various ways and flavors.
Wikipedia lists Standard, CommonMark, GFM and Markdown Extra, but each
implementation of even the same standard may give different results for the same markdown text
([example](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=Here%27s+a+list+of+stuff%3A%0A*+item+one%0A*+item+two%0A*+item+three%0A)).

In spite of the new RFCs, there is no official standard type for email,
but `text/markdown` seems to be the most common de facto type. Most browsers and other 
reasonably sophisticated clients will likely see the `text/` part and default to
`text/plain` anyway, so there's not much difference as regarding email.

If you take a look at the
[Markdown Implementations list](https://www.w3.org/community/markdown/wiki/MarkdownImplementations),
you will see that not even one email client or server is included in it.

There are websites that will convert your markdown to HTML and send the email for you,
for example the commercial [Gmelius](https://gmelius.com/markdown-gmail/),
and PHP also has some markdown modules,
but converters is the most you may expect.

According to comments by @grawity, among the email clients he tested,
only Thunderbird passed it on as Raw data to be displayed.
The others have simply lumped the Markdown inside an attachment.
This means that only Thunderbird paid attention to the `text/` part
in Content-Type, while the others only
treated the entire MIME specification, which to them was unknown since they
don't understand Markdown.

I don't really think that as things stand today using
Markdown is a good idea,
as the wave of markdown incorporation has not reached the
email clients and may never do. In any case, according to the `w3.org`
link above, no email client handles it correctly, so there's really
no point it.

Comment: Please see the comment by @grawity at my answer. Apparently, most mail clients will *not* fall back to text mode, but rather show the markdown as attachment.

Comment: You are actually just stating my concerns: it *should* fall back gracefully, but does it really? I donʼt (yet) expect (m)any clients to convert the markdown code to rich text formatting.

Comment: I have been trying gently to pass on the message that the subject is in evolution, but not recommended at the moment.

Comment: The subject isn't really Markdown -- it's the mail clients' MIME handling in general. If a client supported `text/*` fallback ("...otherwise will fall back to text mode because of the text/ part"), then it would have supported it _regardless_ of Markdown: it would have done the same with `text/rtf`, `text/enriched`, `text/futhark`.

Comment: @grawity: My guess is that a strict email client that only handles known content-types will lump them in an attachment as-is. Thunderbird may be the only client that you tested that intelligently looks at the `text/` part and decides the contents can be good enough to display.

Comment: If @grawity's comments were merged into an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: Did so, and hope that @grawity agrees.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1280912#c4

Answer (score 1):

If the mail has to be single-part, then it can't fallback to text/plain, because there is only the markdown part. You'd be entirely dependent on the markdown support of the recipient's mail client. For multipart messages that contain both text/markdown and text/plain, I guess it might work. Have you actually tried this?

I'm not sure what the current support for Markdown is in mail clients, but I have a gut feeling it's not widely accepted yet. Apart from [this rather old page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/email-client-that-supports-markdown), I can't really find anything.

I just tried to open this message in Outlook (saved as an `.eml` file); it shows as an empty message with a text attachment:

```
From: John Doe <example@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/markdown

# this is the body text
```

Comment: I think the OP meant a different kind of fallback -- not multipart, but simple fallback to showing the contents (source code) without any interpretation when the specific subtype is unrecognized. For example, if a client which doesn't support HTML receives a `text/html`-only message, it will _usually_ show it anyway (as raw HTML tags).

Comment: @grawity Yes that occurred to me too, but we can't be sure. Outlook at least doesn't do this.

Comment: (Quick experiment results: Thunderbird is the only program which renders text/markdown as raw source; most other clients show it as an attachment.)

Comment: @grawity Yes, this is exactly what I was afraid of. It should fall back gracefully, but in some / many clients it wonʼt. After all, Iʼm composing my pain text emails with markdown formatting already, just send as `text/plain`. I *donʼt* want to have them converted to HTML on my side and send as `text/html`.